# I'm having trouble simplifying this equation, can someone help me and let me know what kind of rules were applied to this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for $p_1$:
$1-p_1 = p_1 (\frac {β}{α}+(\frac {β}{α})^2 + (\frac {β}{α})^3+ ...+ (\frac {β}{α})^{n-1})$, we also know that $β = 1-α$.

My teacher's answer is
$$p_1= \frac{1-(\frac {\beta}{\alpha})}{1-(\frac {\beta}{\alpha})^n}$$

But I can't figure out how we got there.

Comment: I'd begin by summing the geometric series.

Comment: Can you please specify how I should go about summing the geometric series? I can't recall any formula for that...

Comment: $\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} x^i$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x \ne 1$
$$1 - p = p (x + x^2+x^3 +...x ^{n-1}) \implies$$
$$1 = p + p (x + x^2+x^3 +...x ^{n-1}) \implies$$
$$1 = p  (1 + x + x^2+x^3 +...x ^{n-1}) \implies$$
$$1 = p  \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} \implies$$
$$p =  \frac{1-x}{1-x^n}$$

If $x = 1$, we get
$$1  = p(1+1+....+1) =  p n \implies p = 1/n$$

Set $x = \beta /\alpha$ and you get the same result as your teacher.